# how to write a function that would return a string in c

Tags: c

How to return a string from the function:

```
char * temp;

int main()
{
    temp = malloc(129);

    double g_symbol_b_amount = 8536.700000;
    printf("\n value: %s\t ", format_double_trans_amount(double g_symbol_b_amount));
}

char *format_double_trans_amount(double amount)
{
    char amount_array_n1[25]; 
    strcpy(amount_array_n, "");
    sprintf(amount_array_n, "%1f", amount);
    temp = amount_array_n;
    return temp;
}
```

Here I got the value: 0.000000
I need the orginal value, please help me on this?

Comment: what is `amount_array_n`? Does this compile for you? Can you show the exact output generated?

Comment: Brain sorry..i done the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the code below and it behaves correctly. Can you please confirm.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

char * temp;

char *format_double_trans_amount(double amount)
{
    sprintf(temp,"%1f",amount);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    double g_symbol_b_amount = 8536.700000;
    temp = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char) * 129);
    printf("\n value: %s\n", format_double_trans_amount(g_symbol_b_amount));
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: @jcrshankar What environment are you using for compiling/testing the example? I've tested with Linux and gcc, and the value is correctly printed!

Comment: @jcrshankar Cool! Do you know what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

Your `printf()` format string should have `%s` instead of `%f` because the value being passed (the value returned from `format_double_trans_amount`) is a `char *` and not a `double`.

I think you should also change your `format_double_trans_amount()` function to:

```
char *format_double_trans_amount(double amount)
{      
    sprintf(temp,"%1f",amount);   
    return temp;  
}
```

Comment: Which is all well and good, except `amount_array_n` in `format_double_trans_amount` doesn't exist. I suspect he doesn't understand that whole stack vs. heap thing either ;)

Comment: @Brian: According to the OP, his code is running and so it must exist, whether we know where or not. However, I've already modified my answer to point out it is not needed.

Comment: Neither is returning anything from `format_double_trans_amount` since `temp` is global. Ignoring the first problem you pointed out which is of course important, his question is asking how you return a "string" from a function.

Comment: @Brian: Your objection appear to be a moving target here :-) but just because a variable is global does not mean it cannot be returned from a function. Clearly, the structure of the code is lacking. But I've corrected the OP's error, and I've made a suggested improvement. I think that's enough to start with.

Comment: @jcrshankar: "nowt working" is not enough information to tell what problems you might still be having.